# Button Position in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to position a button at the bottom of the screen using Xaml or the code behind. This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Here is the Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>


            <Label Text="Identification"
                   x:Name="DriverLabel"/>

            <Image x:Name="VigoLogo"/>

            <Entry Placeholder="Driver Name"
                   Text="{Binding driverID}"/>

    <Button Text="Submit"                               
            Command="{Binding Submit}"
            x:Name="SubmitButton"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            ></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

and the code behind:`

```
// Styling and resources 
            // *************************
            // Whole page ino
            BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            // ID Label at top of screen styles
            DriverLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.LightBlue;
            DriverLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            DriverLabel.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            DriverLabel.FontSize = 20;
            DriverLabel.HeightRequest = 80;
            DriverLabel.TextColor = Color.Black;

            //VigoLogo Information
            VigoLogo.Source = "Resources/vigo_sign.png";


            // Submit button
            SubmitButton.BackgroundColor = Color.LightBlue;
            SubmitButton.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;`
```

I have tried various things with relative and absolute positioning but because I am new to Xamarin I am getting in a mess more than anything else.
I got somewhere using AbsoluteLayout but it seems that only hard coding x and y coordinates works but it needs to be more dynamic than that for different devices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Grid. We can define **4 rows (starting with index '0')**.
The last row (index 3) can be set to take all the remaining space so the button can be placed with **VerticalOptions** to **End** to keep stuck to the bottom.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Identification" Grid.Row="0"
                   x:Name="DriverLabel"/>

            <Image x:Name="VigoLogo" Grid.Row="1"/>

            <Entry Placeholder="Driver Name" Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="{Binding driverID}"/>

    <Button Text="Submit"  Grid.Row="3"                             
            Command="{Binding Submit}"
            x:Name="SubmitButton"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End"
            ></Button>

</Grid>
```

> I suggest you read about Layouts in order to choose the best one for each situation. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts/

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you. I will accept this as son as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

One of them is you using a `StackLayout` wrapping your other views and setting the VerticalOptions to FillAndExpands. This will push the button to the bottom.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Label Text="Identification"
                   x:Name="DriverLabel"/>

            <Image x:Name="VigoLogo" />

            <Entry Placeholder="Driver Name"
                   Text="{Binding driverID}"/>

    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="Submit"                               
            Command="{Binding Submit}"
            x:Name="SubmitButton"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</StackLayout>
```